# Creating objects with relationship in Rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've got a Rails project to do. I'm parsing an .xls file using roo and putting the information in a relational database. How can I get this relationship back if ruby does not use foreign keys ? Suppose I got the Category and Subcategory table, I'm reading the line in the .xls file and writing the information to the database. A category has many subcategories. But there may be an existing category (so I don't need to add it again). Using rails console how would I do it ? I'm using something like `a = Category.new(name_category: "test")`. That should create a category but it's not linked to a subcategory. How would I add and link them together in one command ? What if a subcategory has an item. How would I create something involving 3 relationships ?

Comment: This really depends on your .xls files. Does they contain the subcategory_id or something similar to link an object to another?

Comment: yes, they do. @MrYoshiji

Comment: I wanted a command that would work like that. Even tho' it doesn't work. Category.create(name: "test").subcategory.create(name: "foo"). I know it does not work. Create the relationship in code so rails knows they are linked maybe.. I'm not certain..

Comment: You'll need 2 models at least, what are your skills in Rails in general?

Comment: I got two models. I've created some basic web applications already. Read some books..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't do it in one command. You would need to 'find or create' the Category first.

```
category = Category.find_or_create_by_name(name: "test")
Subcategory.create(name: "foo", category: category)
```

Your models should look like:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :subcategories
end

class Subcategory < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
end
```

Comment: Thank you. I think I can do it now!

Comment: I get this error: ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error: Can't mass-assign protected attributes: category.

Comment: Ahh, you also need this line in your Subcategory model:

    `attr_accessible :subcategory`

Comment: try adding `accepts_nested_attributes_for :category` in the `Subcategory` model